# Proof by induction Computer Science answer

Tags: induction

Here's an attempt :

[image]

I posted needing help for this question earlier

After spending a few hours I think I may have it :P , if not close to finishing it

take(0) = 100-(2*0) = 100 therefore it holds

Assume take(k) = take(k-1)-2 holds to some point of k

prove take(k+1) = take(k)-2

take(k+1)=take(k-1)*-2)-2
take(k+1) = take(k-1)*-2+(-2)

take(k+1)=take(k-2)*4

Comment: In the other thread I was asking for advice on how to approach it, for this i'm asking whether what I've done is correct..

Comment: The way to do that is to edit the other question, not to ask a new one.

Comment: I agree, it's an exact duplicate. He asked the question yesterday...

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought if I edited my post no-one would see it since it's old

Comment: No, if you edit your post, it gets bumped to the top of the front page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If he edits it and includes his answer, that'll invalidate the answers that the earlier question already got. A better approach would be to simply add an *answer* to his original question and accept it.

Comment: @fgp, point taken. Though if OP edits transparently, everyone will see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{take}(k) = \text{take}(k-1)-2$$
is the definition of the function. What you have to show is
$$\text{take}(k)=C - 2k$$ where $C=\text{take}(0)$

Base case $k=0$ is true by choice of $C$.

Assume true for $k-1\ge 0$. Then
$$\text{take}(k) = \text{take}(k-1)-2 = 100 - 2(k-1) - 2 = 100 - 2k$$
So holds for $k$ also.